# Ошибка с количеством сокетов в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

> Starting Ncrack 0.4ALPHA (
> http://ncrack.org ) at 2014-12-08
> 01:38 MSK nsock_core.c:186: Attempt to
> FD_SET fd 1024, which is not less than
> FD_SETSIZE (1024). Try using a lower
> parallelism. QUITTING!

Ошибка с количеством сокетов в ubuntu. Что это такое и как справиться?

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию процессу доступно 1024 файловых дескрипторов (сокет это тоже файловый дескриптор).

Как посмотреть и настроить в конкретной системе можете посмотреть, например http://www.randombugs.com/linux/tuning-file-descriptors-limits-on-linux.html

Вообще же, посмотрите доку к Вашей программе. Скорее всего там есть ключик, задающий ограничение на их использование.

**Update**

```
Why we need to increase the number of file descriptors ?

Heavy loaded servers (but not only them) need that because they are opening a large number of files, sockets or other pseudo files. For each connection a server application will open a new socket and probably other files.

What is the limit of file descriptors per process ?

To see that just run the following command:

    ulimit -n

and you will get the number of file descriptors per your session (process).

How cand I modify the limit of file descriptors per session ?

Edit /etc/security/limits.conf and add:

    *                soft    nofile          65535
    *                hard    nofile          65535

This options will increase the number of file descriptors for all users. If you want just for a specific user replace * with the username. For example if you want to increase the limit for the apache file server just replace * with www-data (Debian specific) and after that just restart the apache (on Debian run: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart)
```

Comment: Ну так просто напишите - `ulimit -n 30000 && your_program`.

Comment: @KoVadim, по моему этот способ только для рута.

Кстати, если надо изменить ограничения только для `your_program`, то так

    (limit -n 30000 && your_program)

Но вот в чем беда, так это в том, что размер `fd_set` не меняется (как был для 1024 дескриптора, так и остался).

Comment: fd_set хоть и равен 1024 дескриптора, но к этому имеет весьма *параллельное* отношение.

команды limit нет. есть ulimit. Даст ли он увеличить до 30000 - не знаю. На федоре без проблем дает увеличить до 3000. Далее - нет.

Comment: Конечно `ulimit`, буковка `u` пропала при копипасте. И *параллельное отношение* тоже верно, программа может и не использовать `fd_set`.

--

На ubunte я проверил -- `(ulimit -n 1041000 && ./a.out)` (потом надоело подбирать).

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка не с количеством сокетов.
В Линукс, по умолчанию, только root может создавать сокеты с номером порта ниже 1024. Для того, чтобы Ваше приложение запустилось запустите его от имени пользователя root (например, используя команду sudo).

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов, где вы вообще здесь увидели номер порта?

Comment: Ссылка недоступна, так какой параметр нужно поменять?

Comment: @Родион Преображен..., если Вы об этой http://www.randombugs.com/linux/tuning-file-descriptors-limits-on-linux.html (странно, у меня точно читается) ссылке, то я вставил в ответ, относящийся к делу, текст из нее.